# when using std::complex<_Float16> for multiplication call to '__constexpr_copysign' is ambiguous c++

Tags: c++, floating-point, stdcomplex

I am trying to use `std::complex<_Float16>` and there is a problem with the `std::operator<_Float16>*()`. Where I get the following error:

```
call to '__constexpr_copysign' is ambiguous
            __a = std::__constexpr_copysign(std::__constexpr_isinf(__a) ? _Tp(1) : _Tp(0), __a);
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::operator*<_Float16>' requested here
        std::complex<_Float16> c = a * b;
                                                                   
                ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:630:54: note: candidate function
_LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR inline _LIBCPP_HIDE_FROM_ABI float __constexpr_copysign(float __x, float __y) _NOEXCEPT {
                                                     ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:634:55: note: candidate function
_LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR inline _LIBCPP_HIDE_FROM_ABI double __constexpr_copysign(double __x, double __y) _NOEXCEPT {
                                                      ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:639:1: note: candidate function
__constexpr_copysign(long double __x, long double __y) _NOEXCEPT {
```

In the above, I have iterators containing `std::complex<_Float16>`, such that this would be a small reproducible example:

```
int main(){
    std::complex<_Float16> a(10.0, 11.2);
    std::complex<_Float16> b(3.0, 4.0);
    std::complex<_Float16> c = a * b;
    return 0;
}
```

Which caused the error above. How could I fix this without modifying the cmath file?

Comment: Where are you getting `float16_t` from? Are you compiling with c++23?

Comment: It certainly seems that Xcode does not support types other than `float`, `double`, and `long double`.  One solution would be to use a better standard library.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox I made an alias from the gcc type `_Float16` to `float16_t` I changed it in the code above.

Comment: @DrewDormann the thing is that a `_Float16` times another `_Float16` is entirely valid. The above without the `std::complex` wrapping it would be entirely valid. I am just wondering why `std::complex<_Float16>` times another `std::complex<_Float16>` is not. From the error, it states ambiguity, meaning `_Float16` could probably convert to `double` and `float` as far as Xcode is concerned which would make it ambiguous. I am just kind of wondering if I can fix that in some way.

Comment: Your standard library was written such that exactly three versions of your multiply exist, and none of the versions are float16.  That's what your error is telling you.  How to solve that?  I made one suggestion, above.

Comment: This appears to work in gcc 13.2: https://godbolt.org/z/6G6jKdT37. What compiler version are you using?

Comment: @FantasticMrFox I have clang version 15.0.0 which I’m assuming is gcc 13.2?

Comment: @SamMoldenha clan 15.0.0 also appears to compile correctly: https://godbolt.org/z/qnPqd8sWG Can you use godbolt to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @FantasticMrFox the same version of clang I am using, that I re-produce with gobolt, works differently. ie the version on my computer gives me an error while gobolt does not. I am wondering if I should re-install clang on my computer.